# inner css and css file overlap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on, mobile web adaptation for mvc4 project.

Desktop design is finished and they want me to make this website working on mobile devices correct.

There are several problems that I need to handle with.
1- They use bootstrap but they also put some inner css codes.Like the code below

```
<div class="col-md-2 pull-right" style="text-align: right;margin-right:-12px">
```

2- They also have other specific files and they did not code responsive. They gave specific values for blocks, Like the code below

```
fieldset
{
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}
```

Now what I am doing is I created a new css file and I want to create a superficial solution for this problem. Below is my css file. I am working for smaller sizes of 568px;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width:568px)" href="~/Content/Iphone.css">
```

My problem is They use inner css for some div blocks and classes and I am not able to remove those lines. For example

```
<div class="col-md-2 pull-right" style="text-align: right;margin-right:-12px">
```

I dont need margin-right:-12px but how to handle this error without removing this code. I try to create id for it but this inner css and it is gonna work last.

I need some advices for those problems

Comment: you can't, really. `style="..."` attributes on an element will always override CSS defined in `<style>` and external `<link>`'d files. Your only option would be to use `!important` and hope that they don't have any `!important` of their own in the `style` attribute.

Comment: That is what I want to say, they coded like this and now they want me to fix and also they dont want me remove any lines , make any changes for the original code

Comment: Thank You Marc this is a horrible solution I know but there is no way for me. That is not my fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a horrible solution and I would not recommend it but you can use

```
!important
```

Like so

```
background: #000 !important;
```

This will overwrite the inline style.

But I would honestly recommend removing the inline style and putting it in a style sheet if you can.

Comment: This is correct. Your only option is using `!important` to override the inline styles, but ideally you should get rid of the inline styles

Comment: Thank you lukehillonline, I know this is a terrible solution but, I have go with this. That is not my problem but anyway Thank you for your help